# Use psql --set variable in a function

Tags: postgresql, scripting, postgresql-9.5, psql

I want to create a script that will create some custom named schema and within it some tables and functions. Like this:

The `example.sh` file:

```
#!/bin/bash

# this is the only place I want to set the schema name
SCH="ex"

export SCH

export PGPASSWORD="*******"

PSQL="psql \
  -X \
  -U postgres \
  -h localhost \
  --single-transaction \
  --echo-all \
  --set SCH=$SCH \
  --set ON_ERROR_STOP=on "

eval $PSQL "-f ./example.sql"
```

The `example.sql` file:

```
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS :SCH CASCADE;
CREATE SCHEMA :SCH;

CREATE TABLE :SCH.my_table
(
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  my_col text
);

INSERT INTO :SCH.my_table (my_col) VALUES ('abc'), ('def');

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION :SCH.getLast()
RETURNS text AS $$
SELECT my_col FROM :SCH.my_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;

SELECT * FROM :SCH.getLast();
```

It works fine until the:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION :SCH.getLast()
RETURNS text AS $$
SELECT my_col FROM :SCH.my_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```

As the function body is a text constant, the `:SCH` is not substituted by the schema name and we get an error:

```
psql:./example.sql:16: ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
LINE 3: SELECT my_col FROM :SCH.my_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Is there a neat way to make it work?

## Workaround

This can be done in the following way, but it seems there should be an easier way:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION :SCH.makeFunction(schema_name text)
RETURNS VOID AS $body$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION %1$s.getLast()
    RETURNS text AS $$
    SELECT my_col FROM %1$s.my_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
    $$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;', schema_name);
END
$body$ LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE;

SELECT :SCH.makeFunction(:'SCH');
```

Answer (score 5):

An interesting way of achieving this is using a `psql` variable to store the whole function body, like

```
\set body '$$SELECT 1$$'

CREATE FUNCTION bla() RETURNS integer LANGUAGE SQL AS :c;

SELECT bla();
 bla 
─────
   1
```

Alternatively, you can pass the whole definition into the variable, and then run it:

```
\set function 'CREATE FUNCTION bla() RETURNS integer LANGUAGE SQL AS $$SELECT 1;$$;'

:function

SELECT bla();
 bla 
─────
   1
```

So, the question is how to put the body into a suitable variable.

From `psql` 9.3 above, there is the `\gset` command, that comes to the rescue.  We build a query that produces the function body as an output, then assign it to a `psql` variable, and use it like above (with [`format()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html#FUNCTIONS-STRING-FORMAT)):

```
SELECT format('CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION %1$s.getLast()
    RETURNS text AS $$
    SELECT my_col FROM %1$s.my_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
    $$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE;', 'test') AS function;

\gset

:function
```

And done.

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative to prefixing all objects with the schema-qualifier `:SCH` variable, you may assign `search_path`, so that it happens automatically.

```
CREATE SCHEMA :"SCH";
SET search_path TO :"SCH";
```

After this, all CREATE statements and type lookups happen in `:SCH`.

Concerning queries inside the bodies of functions, by default they still use whatever is the `search_path` at run-time, but this can be changed with an explicit `SET` associated to the function's declaration.

For example `getLast()` could be declared in the SQL script as:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION getLast()
RETURNS text AS $$
  SELECT my_col FROM my_table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1;
$$ LANGUAGE sql STABLE SET search_path TO :"SCH";
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I'll say that if you can use @daniel-vérité's solution and set the search_path, do that.  If you need to interpolate a variable for more than schema scoping, @dezso's answer works, but can be refined and simplified slightly.

A solution here can be found by realizing that the regular syntax for creating a function already uses a *string* as the body of the function.

```
CREATE FUNCTION :SCH.getLast() ... AS <somestring>;
```

So embedding a psql script variable in the function body boils down to figuring out how to embed that into a string.  For readability, use `$$` instead of single quotes, set the psql variable with gset, then interpolate it *as a string* with `:'<varname>'` (note the quotes).

```
SELECT $$
BEGIN
    SELECT my_col FROM $$ || :SCH || $.my_table ORDER by id DESC LIMIT 1;
END
$$ as funcbody
\gset

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION :SCH.getLast()
RETURNS text AS :'funcbody'
LANGUAGE sql STABLE;
```